# Difference between WiFi-Direct Api and Alljoyn framework

Tags: android, wifi-direct, alljoyn

i want to build an android application using Wifi peer to peer without to be connected to internet, and without using an AP (Access Point) , so i wonder, if it's better to use the WiFi-Direct Api, or the framework Alljoyn to build it ? (i think that this last one is doing the same thing like The WiFi-Direct Api, but with using an AP).
Please anyone can explain to me this point.
Thanks in advence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AllJoyn is an higher level  framework that does most of the plumbing for you, basically you define an interface, register it, create a session and your good to go. It works over IP (so WiFi with an AP for example) and has special code for wifi direct (buy not officially supported now) and there's a partial Bluetooth LE implementation  (but which currently requires a rooted android phone).

There's a description of what's officially supported in this forum post : https://allseenalliance.org/developer-resources/forum/developers/how-alljoyn-works-mobile-devices

You can do all of this by yourself over WiFi or WiFi direct, but it would a lot more work (you'll have to implement discovery, marshaling, etc yourself).

Comment: So Alljoyn can work too without access point ? , if yes, can u give me a link to start with ? thanks for your repley.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, wifi direct is not currently officially supported. But as there is definitely code about it, one can hope it will be restored.

Comment: okey, then what's officially supported is that applications can connect to each other with Alljoyn, on condition that they should be connected to the same network, wich means the same access point. am i wrong ?. thanks again.

Comment: You're right, that's what is officially supported (although the code can do more)

Comment: Another question, in the case that i want to build an android application connecting devices to each other through an ad hoc network, can i consider that WiFi-Direct API is the unique way to build it ? (without Alljoyn).

Comment: Afaik yes (but connection must be manually acceptedby the user) Also please don't forget this is not a forum and create a new question if needed.

Comment: my suggestion is that you should use alljoyn instead of usual Wifi Direct API because AllJoyn works for Android 2.2> and not just Android 4.